# How to unregister "httpd" after "wfsctl stop"?

Tags: high-sierra, http, webdav

**How does one properly unregister `httpd` from launching at reboot following a `sudo wfsctl start` and subsequent `sudo wfsctl stop`?**

**Background:**

`wfsctl` is a "WebDAV File Sharing control utility" released with macOS High Sierra. `wfsctl` is located at `/usr/sbin/wfsctl`.

In my case, after an initial install of macOS High Sierra, the Apache `httpd` daemon is not initially serving content. (This was expected.)  The observation that httpd was not serving could observed in various ways, including:

- type `localhost` into a web browser on the same machine
- type `curl localhost` in the terminal on the same machine.

```sh
curl localhost
# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

When the `wfsctl` WebDAV services are started for the first time, then `httpd` is also started.

```sh
sudo wfsctl start
# ... 
sudo wfsctl diagnose
# ... snip ...
# All httpd processes:
# COMM             RUSER             PPID   PID STARTED
# httpd            root                 1   885  4:18PM
# httpd            _www               885   890  4:18PM
```

It was not surprising that an Apache `httpd` was started.  Although, the baseline Apache `httpd` configuration also start serviing the contents of /Library/WebServer/Documents in addition to and separate from any WebDAV shares. In particular, `index.html` content is returned via either `localhost` in a web browser or `curl localhost` in the Terminal application.

```sh
curl localhost --verbose
# * Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
# > GET / HTTP/1.1
# > Host: localhost
# > User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
# > Accept: */*
# > 
# < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
# < Server: Apache/2.4.28 (Unix) mod_secure_transport/2.4.27
# < Content-Location: index.html.en
# <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Finally, stop the WebDAV services with `sudo wfsctl stop`, then reboot. After reboot, `httpd` is apparently still running:

```sh
# after `sudo wfsctl stop` and system reboot ...
curl localhost
# <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>

sudo wfsctl status
# disabled

sudo wfsctl diagnose
# ...
# WFS is not enabled.
# ...
# All httpd processes:
# COMM   RUSER  PPID   PID STARTED
# httpd  root      1    85  6:12PM
# httpd  _www     85   414  6:13PM
```

**Footnote:**
Is it a reasonably expected behaviour that `sudo wfsctl stop` *does not also unregister `httpd`*?

Perhaps `wfsctl` presumes to not interfere with other services with *might* be used to start the `httpd` web server?  (Though, in my use case, `httpd` was not enabled via any other means than `wfsctl`.)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the question, `sudo wfsctl stop` does not stop and unregister the `httpd` process. However, the `httpd` daemons are stopped and restarted. Also, `httpd` remains registered to start on the next (re)boot.

```sh
sudo wfsctl diagnose
# All httpd processes:
# COMM   RUSER   PPID   PID STARTED
# httpd  root       1   325  8:46PM
# httpd  _www     325   331  8:46PM
sudo wfsctl stop
sudo wfsctl diagnose
# All httpd processes:
# COMM    RUSER  PPID   PID STARTED
# httpd   root      1   399 10:19PM
# httpd   _www    399   403 10:19PM
```

The `man wfsctl` mentions that the use of `httpd-wrapper` is preferred to the use of `apachectl` and `httpd` (at least for the `-t` test flag.)

> The Apache config file for WebDAV File Sharing is parameterized, and the httpd server is managed by the `httpd-wrapper` utility, which passes parameters to `httpd`. This is normally transparent, but note that to check the Apache config file syntax, do not use `apachectl configtest` or `httpd -t`. Instead, use `httpd-wrapper -t`.

In general, the options shown in the `man httpd` page can be passed to the `/usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper` ruby script. Most of the options work as expected.

However, `sudo httpd-wrapper -k graceful-stop` behaves like a reset which restarts the `httpd` daemons and leaves `httpd` registered to start when the system boots again.

Finally, `sudo apachectl graceful-stop` was found to stop and unregister the `httpd` processes.

So, the following command sequence will stop both the `wfsctl` WebDAV sharing and the `httpd` daemons on the current High Sierra.

```sh
sudo wfsctl stop
# Unloaded and removed: org.apache.httpd.webdavfilesharing.username-275.49176.plist
sudo apachectl graceful-stop
# verify
sudo wfsctl diagnose
```

---

See ["How to set up `wfsctl` WebDAV to use with an application that uses basic authentication?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314689/how-to-set-up-wfsctl-webdav-to-use-with-an-application-that-uses-basic-authent/315506#315506) for a more complete WebDAV example.