# How to set up macOS High Sierra "wfsctl" WebDAV to use with an application that uses basic authentication?

Tags: high-sierra, http, webdav

**How does one go about setting up a macOS High Sierra `wfsctl` WebDAV server to use with application such as Password Wallet?** *Does any one have a good set of notes for setting up a `wfsctl` server?*

**Use Case**

`wfsctl` WebDAV server now ships with macOS High Sierra. The context of this question is for mainstream macOS High Sierra, and not any macOS Server software.

Applications (such as PasswordWallet) would use basic username password authentication to access a WebDAV server.

**Background:**

At this time, search on various `apple.com` urls only returned one result, ["Prepare your institution for ... macOS High Sierra ..."](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207828), which just states:

> You won’t be able to set up file sharing with iOS devices in macOS Server 5.4. ... If you want to configure WebDAV sharing on a Mac with macOS Server 5.4, see the wfsctl(8) manual page.

The `wfsctl` man page (on regular macOS High Sierra) provides technical command information. However, the man page does not provide a example setup or getting started guide.

So far, internet searches for `wfsctl` use on macOS High Sierra has not yielded much additional information about using `wfsctl`.

Finally, while there are many Apache WebDAV guides available, my initial `wfsctl` experimenting started with the *unexpected* [`wfsctl` will `start` but not `stop` the related Apache `httpd` services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314614/how-to-unregister-httpd-after-wfsctl-stop).

So, does any one have a good set of summary notes specific to setting up a `wfsctl` WebDAV server and how to navigate through any "quirks" of a `wfsctl` system? (i.e. not general Apache WebDAV links.)

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1. Host Address.** Know the IP address or DNS Domain Name for the host machine. A *static IP address* or *fully qualified DNS name* will allow other guest machines to bookmark the host machine. If DHCP is used for the host machine, then the dynamic TCP/IP address will need to be known each time prior to connection. The IP address can be found in the System Preferences > Network panel.

[image: Network IP]

**Step 2. Create Share Point Directory.**

```sh
# For example,
sudo mkdir /Library/WebServer/ExampleSharePoint
sudo chown $USER:staff /Library/WebServer/ExampleSharePoint
sudo wfsctl share Volume/HardDisk/Library/WebServer
```

**Step 3. Configuration.**  Edit `/etc/wfs/wfs.plist`. Set `SynthesizeSharePointForUserHomeDir` to determine whether to allow remote WebDAV clients to see their home directory as a share point. Default is `true`.  Use `false` to limit sharing to the expressly added share points.

```xml
<key>SynthesizeSharePointForUserHomeDir</key>
<false/>
```

*Note: `CreateHomeDirsForLocalUsers` and `ApplyUserInstanceSandbox` appear to be undocumented at this time.*

**Step 4. Start `wfsctl`.**

```sh
sudo wfsctl start
# Using identity with self-signed cert
sudo wfsctl diagnose # verify
```

**Step 5. Setup Application Connection.**

In the case of PasswordWallet, use the Network Sync Wizard to create a new sync.  Select WebDAV as the sync type.

[image: Sync Type]

If the server does not have a fully qualified DNS name, then the IP address can be used directly.

[image: Sync Info]

**Step 6. Stopping `wfsctl` and `httpd`.**

Based on [How to unregister “httpd” after “wfsctl stop”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314614/how-to-unregister-httpd-after-wfsctl-stop) ...

```sh
sudo wfsctl stop             # stops WebDAV. restarts httpd
sudo apachectl graceful-stop # if desired, stops httpd
# verify
sudo wfsctl diagnose
```

---

**Addendum**

The WebDAV share can also be mounted directly from macOS Finder. Menu: Finder > Go > Connect to Server… `⌘K`.

[image: Finder Connect to Server]

The default auto self-generated certificate can be either temporarily or permanently accepted.

[image: Verify Certificate]

*Finder Share Point Folder View*

[image: Finder Share Point Folder View]

*Finder Share Point Info*

[image: Finder Share Point Info]

Observation: Sometimes a file transfer via a macOS Finder WebDAV mount could fail and cause a loss of connection.  In these cases, so far, a second transfer attempt has succeeded OK.

At the time of this writing, the Password Wallet direct WebDAV synchronization connection has been solid and reliable for me.